# Do I have to waste time on Webflow for animations or just use skills with JavaScript

Tags: animation, webflow

I saw in ads for Webflow and tried a little but i don't know if its worth for animations or do I have to make simply with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make websites quickly and need to do complex animations then I recommend you to use webflow, considering that fact, if you are not from a programming background. You can easily make websites visually(it's a visual composer) using webflow.